# Error with TransformPoint(x,y) gdal

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo, osr

```py
from osgeo import gdal,ogr,osr

def GetExtent(ds):
    """ Return list of corner coordinates from a gdal Dataset """
    xmin, xpixel, _, ymax, _, ypixel = ds.GetGeoTransform()
    width, height = ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize
    xmax = xmin + width * xpixel
    ymin = ymax + height * ypixel

    return (xmin, ymax), (xmax, ymax), (xmax, ymin), (xmin, ymin)

def ReprojectCoords(coords,src_srs,tgt_srs):
    """ Reproject a list of x,y coordinates. """
    trans_coords=[]
    transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation( src_srs, tgt_srs)
    for x,y in coords:
        x,y,z = transform.TransformPoint(x,y)
        trans_coords.append([x,y])
    return trans_coords
```

When I execute this code I got an error :

Here is my execution :

```py
raster=r'IMG_PHR1B_MS_002/IMG_PHR1B_MS_202104211119066_SEN_6005996101-2_R1C1.JP2'
ds=gdal.Open(raster)
ext=GetExtent(ds)
src_srs=osr.SpatialReference()
src_srs.ImportFromWkt(ds.GetProjection())
#tgt_srs=osr.SpatialReference()
#tgt_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
tgt_srs = src_srs.CloneGeogCS()
geo_ext=ReprojectCoords(ext, src_srs, tgt_srs)
```

[image]

I don't know what it means, because when I search other examples in StackOverflow etc..., they all work with only two args.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Error messages and code should be posted as text, not as a screenshot. It is very difficult to read for some users and impossible for screen readers, and google. Please take the [tour] to see how this site works.